# Older craftsman lawn mower 14 HP popped out of neutral to first gear

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, shifting, gears, lawnmower

I was running gas out of mower while it was in neutral, it jumped gears and started climbing a milk crate. I could backup off milk crate, so I run gas out of mower while holding clutch in until motor stopped. I think a spring broke, but have no idea what to do to mower. It is in first gear I believe. It made no noise when jumped gears and climbed crate. It had plenty of power. Need to know how to start motor in wrong gear.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm not sure I'm following you here. Is there any way to clarify exactly what you're asking? You are saying the mower is stuck in first gear, so you have no way of clutching it to release the transmission? And you cannot shift it out of gear while the mower is off? Can you provide the exact model of mower?There should be a data plate on the mower (and a separate one on the engine). If you can get us the part number from the mower itself, we can look it up on the Sears website and possibly get you some answers.

Comment: I was able to clutch the mower while gas ran out of mower.It started climbing milk crate when it jumped out of neutral. I will get the model number tomorrow and email you back. Thanks again.